# .htaccess url rewriting not working

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I'm using URL Rewriting for a simple note application in my website. All things are  UNDER `/notes/` directory. `.htaccess` contents are,

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?filename=$1 [L]
```

and the url which is to be accessed is,

```
http://localhost/notes/test.txt
```

I want to get **test.txt** as the `filename` variable's value.

But when I use `echo $_GET['filename'];` in `index.php`, it displays `index.php` instead of displaying `test.txt`.

here, `test.txt` is not a real text file but the `filename` variable's value.

Comment: Did the answer fix your problem?

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem is that your "index.php?filename=test.txt" URL is also being processed and rewritten by your rule. You might need to change your `.htaccess` code to stop references to files that exist being rewritten:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?filename=$1 [L]
```